# How to infer subtype in supertype

Tags: java

Say you have a super-class. In that super class you want to pass runtime object of itself (`this`) as a parameter to an overloaded method. Trick is, this overloaded method is overloaded by sub-class type. When you try to do it, you'll get a

> method ... is not applicable(actual argument
>   ... cannot be converted to ... by method invocation
>   conversion)

Instead you would need to implement the method separately in each subtype (just to get the correct runtime class), which is a lot of duplicate effort when the contents of the method are identical.

e.g:

```
public class InferTypeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass1 s1 = new SubClass1();
        s1.sayHi();
    }

    public static void sayHi(SubClass1 clz) {
        System.out.println("clz 1");
    }

    private abstract static class SuperClass{
        public void sayHi() {
            InferTypeTest.sayHi(this);
        }
    }

    private static class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{

    }

}
```

Comment: I want to say that there's got to be some better way to design this whole structure, but it's really hard to pick out the core of the problem based on the code you've provided.  Can you simplify the example?

Comment: Umm, it's a rather straightforward Visitor pattern... (Contrived of course). Ok, i do get your point though.

Comment: Ok, simplified the example code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is how double dispatch works, you have to override the accept method in each subclass like this:

```
    private static abstract class NodeWithChildren implements DomNode {
        /* snip */
        public void accept(DomNodeVisitor visitor) {
            for (DomNode child : children) {
                child.accept(visitor);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class BodyNode extends NodeWithChildren {
        public void accept(DomNodeVisitor visitor) {
            visitor.visit(this);
            super.accept(visitor);
            visitor.visited(this);
        }
    }

    private static class DivNode extends NodeWithChildren {
        public void accept(DomNodeVisitor visitor) {
            visitor.visit(this);
            super.accept(visitor);
            visitor.visited(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BodyNode is a NodeWithChildren
    DivNode is a NodeWithChidren
    NodeWithChildren is a DomNode
    DomPrinterVisitor is a DomNodeVisitor
    DomNodeVisitor's visitor can visit "BodyNode" or "DivNode,  But you are passing "NodeWithChildren" to visit.
    Here BodyNode is a NodeWithChildren but NodeWithChildren is not BodyNode/

```
Theary is if B extends A, you can say B is a A/ not A is a B.
```

Comment: Could you go back and revise this a bit?  It's very unclear to me at a first glance.

Comment: So, in short, in Java you can't refer to the runtime type of an object?

Comment: This is not about the support of Java/ Its purely about object orientation. The code is trying to violate object orientation principle.

Comment: Ok. In the example (updated) SuperClass is abstract - at runtime you can't have an instance of SuperClass. Wouldn't it make sense to have some kind of support for the actual runtime type of an object? I do understand your point (A != B) but this is compile time.